# MySQL FOR UPDATE clause concurrency issue

Tags: mysql, concurrency, vb6

We have a table that contains records that refer to a counter for each transaction our system handles.

Here is the table definition of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `controlnumber` (
  `StoreCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `TerminalNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `TransactionType` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `LastSeries` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Prefix` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StoreCode`,`TerminalNumber`,`TransactionType`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

A sample of the data from the table is as follows:

```
+------------+----------------------+------------+
| LastSeries | TransactionType      | StoreCode  |
+------------+----------------------+------------+
|          1 |   Adjustments        | HeadOffice |
|     111982 |   Direct Transfer    | HeadOffice |
|        975 |   Location Transfer  | HeadOffice | 
|       8065 |   Receiving          | HeadOffice |
+------------+----------------------+------------+
```

When creating a transaction that uses this table, the code is as follows:

Application Code (vb6):

```
connection.BeginTrans
connection.execute("CALL saveReceiving(...)")
connection.execute("UPDATE controlnumber SET lastSeries = lastSeries + 1 WHERE TransactionType = 'Receiving' AND StoreCode = ...")
connection.CommitTrans
```

SQL Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE saveReceiving(...)
BEGIN
    //The "receiving" table is an InnoDB table
    INSERT INTO receiving (receivingnumber, transactiondate, ...) VALUES (createTransID('Receiving'), NOW(), ...);
END
```

The definition of the `createTransID` MySQL function is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION createTransID(TransactionType VARCHAR(15), pStoreCode VARCHAR(15)) 
 BEGIN

  DECLARE returnValue VARCHAR(45);
  CASE TransactionType
  ....
  WHEN 'Receiving' THEN
    SELECT CONCAT(Prefix,'-', LastSeries + 1) INTO returnValue FROM controlnumber WHERE StoreCode = pStoreCode FOR UPDATE;
  ...
  END

  RETURN returnValue;
 END
```

Now I assume that when using the `FOR UPDATE` clause, I am locking the records for the `controlnumber` table and no other user can access it Thus, preventing 
multiple users from getting the same `lastSeries` value. But the reality is that multiple users can get the same `lastSeries` value. What am I doing wrong here?

- Server: MySQL 5.7.17 on windows server 2012 R2
- ODBC connector: MySQL ODBC 3.51.30 on windows 10
- MySQL config file: http://pastebin.com/5HeHDRLe